# Python Aes-256 GMC decrypt error at decode result

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I'm facing a issue to decrypt data that was encrypted in Node JS into python code:

```
Error at "return decrypted.decode('utf-8')"
Error: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

any idea why?

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

args = {
    "content": "725cd5204cf64987a39a6622884527e0",
    "iv": "e6174b11cd2a18fc",
    "tag": {
        "data": [26, 91, 205, 206, 134, 22, 167, 101, 110, 27, 155, 100, 41, 99, 34, 135],
        "type": "Buffer"
    },
    "key": "SqqUUMnwEVUCBYT7p/0Zfz4Cq2eazHqQ"
}

def decrypt_auth_tag(args):
    try:
        key = args["key"]
        content = bytes.fromhex(args["content"])
        iv = bytes.fromhex(args["iv"])
        tag = bytes(args["tag"]["data"])
        
        cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=iv)
        cipher.update(tag)
        decrypted = cipher.decrypt(content)
        return decrypted.decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)

print(decrypt_auth_tag(args))
```

The encryption is done by a serve which I don't have access to, but I have the version in node js who works really well to decrypt I just need same version in Python code.

Here the version in Node that works to decrypt:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let args = {
    "content": "725cd5204cf64987a39a6622884527e0",
    "iv": "e6174b11cd2a18fc",
    "tag":
    {
        "data": [26, 91, 205, 206, 134, 22, 167, 101, 110, 27, 155, 100, 41, 99, 34, 135],
        "type": "Buffer"
    }
}
// Decrypts the data using a key, iv, and auth tag
function decryptAuthTag(args) {
    try {
        const key = "SqqUUMnwEVUCBYT7p/0Zfz4Cq2eazHqQ";
        const encrypted = {
            content: args.content,
            iv: args.iv,
            tag: args.tag
        };

        const alg = 'aes-256-gcm';
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(alg, key, encrypted.iv);
        decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(encrypted.tag));
        let dec = decipher.update(encrypted.content, 'hex', 'utf8');
        dec += decipher.final('utf8');
        return dec;
    } catch (error) {
        return "ERROR"
    }
}

console.log(decryptAuthTag(args))
```

Comment: Have you printed `decrypted` to see what you're actually getting?  You need to know whether it is garbage or not.

Comment: The code is a sample to decode, that has to return '4194590036837597' as decripted, that information as valdiate previously in Node just to make sure it works.

Comment: It may be a good idea to show the encoding node.js snippet too.

Comment: i dont have the encoding code, but i just added the version of decription in node js that works really wellm hope that helps.

Comment: @TimRoberts the `decrypted` is comming as b'\xc8\xff\xeaI\x0c\xcb2\x95\xcbO\xf6\xfc\x0c\n\x85\xa2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decryption works if the IV is UTF-8 encoded (and not hex decoded):

```py
iv = args["iv"].encode('utf-8')
```

---

Note that `decrypt()` only decrypts without prior authentication. Also, [`update()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html?highlight=aes%20gcm#update) does not specify the tag, but the additional authenticated data (AAD). The incorrect use of `cipher.update(tag)` has no effect here only because of the missing authentication.

In order for the data to be authenticated before decryption (as is intended), [`decrypt_and_verify()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html?highlight=aes%20gcm#decrypt_and_verify) must be applied, passing ciphertext and tag:

```py
decrypted = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(content, tag)
```

With this change, of course, the `cipher.update(tag)` line must be removed, otherwise authentication will fail and no decryption will be performed.

---

Regarding the IV size: For performance and compatibility reasons, the recommended IV size for GCM is 12 bytes (the posted example uses a size of 16 bytes).